# Rename files if already exists centos7

Tags: file, ftp, centos, filenames, centos7

I have a vsftpd installed in my centos 7 server.

The problem is that i have mutiple clients sent files concurrently to the same ftp, and i am not able to rename the client file.
The filename is always the date of the moment.

eg 150616160005.txt

15-year

06-month

16-day

16-hour

00-min

05-second

Sometimes diferent clients send files with the same name.
So im looking for a solution like windows, if file exists the new file is renamed for 150616160005(1).txt instead of overwrite.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want the server to prevent the collisions? Or a client-side solution? In any case, the question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please move it to [su].

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes i want the server to prevent the collisions.
How can i move it?

Comment: Delete here and re-post on [su] or [sf].